# Update a null column in sql with spexecutesql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sp-executesql

I encountered a problem in the following query. When I go to update the column ID_Premesso with the value NULL the value does not change, while if I go to update with the value 0 it works.

```
    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @NameTB + ' SET ID_Permesso = NULL WHERE ID_Timbratura = @IDTimbratura ' 
    SET @PARAMS = '@IDTimbratura INT'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @PARAMS, @IDTimbratura;
```

Comment: I *hope* you are properly quoting the value of `@NameTB` before you inject it into your dynamic statement. If not, this is very likely wide open to injection attacks.

Comment: Why would you hardcode the column names of a table but not the name of the table itself? This looks like a schema problem - one shouldn't have multiple tables containing the same columns. And why would such a table allow NULL for a column whose name sounds like an identifier?

Comment: I would *guess* it's a foreign key, @SMor .

Comment: Let's see the table schema, and lets' see how you declare those variables

Comment: The table name is built inside the stored vine and is not passed externally by a parameter, I have several identical tables divided for years to speed up the query. But the problem is another if somehow with sp_executesql it is possible to update a column by setting the value to null

Answer (score 2):

`=` does not work for `NULL` values.  So, if `ID_Timbratura` can be `NULL`, you need to take that into account:

```
    SET @SQL = '
UPDATE ' + @NameTB + '
    SET ID_Permesso = NULL
    WHERE ID_Timbratura = @IDTimbratura OR
          (ID_Timbratura IS NULL AND @IDTimbratura IS NULL)' ;

    SET @PARAMS = N'@IDTimbratura INT';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @PARAMS, @IDTimbratura;
```

Note that SQL Server lets you break strings over multiple lines.  I reformatted the query string so it is easier to read.

Comment: But it is not Timing_ID which is null but Allowed_ID which must become null. Maybe I expressed myself badly

Comment: @Rosko . . . There is no `Allowed_ID` in your query.  Using `NULL` for `ID_Permesso` is fine.